# How to handle comma in a cell in csv file in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, csv

How can I handle the comma in address cell while reading the csv?

"node_id","name","address","country_codes","countries","sourceID","valid_until","note"

"14000008","","""Les Tattes""; Bursinel; Vaud; Switzerland","CHE","Switzerland","Panama Papers","Through 2015",""

"14000014","","""Whingate"" Tower Hill Dummer, Nr Basingstoke; Hants RG25 2AL","GBR","United Kingdom","Panama Papers","Through 2015",""

"14000015","","#02-01; 14 MOHAMED SULTAN ROAD; SINGAPORE 238963","SGP","Singapore","Panama Papers","Through 2015",""

Answer (score 0):

You can use some fancy stuff like a Regex:

1. Splitter.on(Pattern.compile(",(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)"))

Or you can try to use split() function with delimiter:

```
scala> val s = "eggs, milk, butter, Coco Puffs"
s: java.lang.String = eggs, milk, butter, Coco Puffs

scala> s.split(",") //split function
res0: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(eggs, " milk", " butter", " Coco Puffs")
```